# Javascript fail to excute HTTP request

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have the following code which fails when I try to execute it in my browser:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=464891386855067&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=basic_info,email,public_profile,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_friends,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details&response_type=token", false);
req.send();
var responseURL = req.responseURL;
console.log(responseURL);
```

I get the following error:

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=464891386855067&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=basic_info,email,public_profile,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_friends,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_relationship_details&response_type=token'.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here? I was pretty sure the code was gonna work.

Comment: Are you getting this thing in Error output : **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: Assuming this URL works when you simply browse to it? Have you tried to check network activity with firebug, chrome F12, IE8+ "development tools" or similar?

Comment: It works when I access the link in the browser. I have the file in htdocs running Apache server btw.

Comment: I cant see that I'm getting access-control-allow-origin error

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Is your file containing the JS definitely loaded over http? or accessed through file///?

Comment: I'm tryging to get my user token from facebook for the app id in the URL.

Comment: I've been trying with normal web sites, and it is still not working. I'm sure it is running on the apache server